# Gcc address sanitizer offline

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

I'm using GCC 4.8.1 with address sanitizer option turned on, i.e. I'm compiling and linking using `-fsanitize=address`. With this old version GCC doesn't provide a worth output. It needs a symbolizer. No need for extra applications on newer versions. I can't install LLVM packages on target machine, so my question is: is it possible to perform the analysis offline? I mean: can I get the output from the target machine and then analyze the result using symbolizer on the development machine?

Comment: Whan is the version of gcc on another machine? gcc ABIs must be compatible between those machines. You would need a static library of the symbolizer to link with it.

Comment: always 4.8.1 but with llvm-symbolizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe unsymbolized output of sanitized executable to [asan_symbolize script](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/lib/asan/scripts/asan_symbolize.py), either on target or on development machine.

Note that by default `asan_symbolize` tries to locate symbols in executables on machine it's run on. When if target and development executables do not match you'll need to use `-s` flag to specify target sysroot.